# Invalid input syntax for type date: "\N" in postgresql when fetching data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using **postgresql** and getting this sql error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   invalid input syntax for type date: "\N"

Here is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE  person.dob = '\N' OR person.dob = '1994-01-16';
```

How can I allow Null values? so what should I add to this SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this following code:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE  person.dob is null OR person.dob = '1994-01-16';
```

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin Fantastic! don't forget accept the answer :)

Comment: of course but it says I need to wait 6 mins so I'm waiting :)

Comment: also for updating and inserting(nulls) what should I use?

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin Aah ah ah... for that answer is another price ;)

Comment: ahahahha come on :)))

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin just kiding, is a little abstract the question, for a column? insert null, but in what case? and update in what case? I think maybe you should ask a new answer with more details, maybe, but believe me is very similar

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin please don't take me wrong, I make that advice so we can avoid a mix of topics in the same question, it's confusing for the future readers

Comment: yeah yeah true no problem at all, i did not get you wrong everything is cool :)